# How to pipe two output files to bgzip them?

Tags: linux, io, pipe, output, gzip

I'm running a command that generates two output files, those two files are very large and I would want to pipe the output to be bgzipped, rather than run bgzip on  the output after it was written.

These are my current commands:

```
samtools sort -n --threads 16  -l 0 $file --reference $ref.fa | samtools fastq  - -1 $file_1.fastq -2 $file_2.fastq
bgzip $file_1.fastq
bgzip $file_2.fastq
```

Is it possible to do all of those in one command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

```
samtools sort -n --threads 16  -l 0 $file --reference $ref.fa | samtools fastq - -1 >(pigz -p 12 > $file_1.fastq.gz) -2 >(pigz -p 12 > $file_2.fastq.gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do those "-1" and "-2" flags mean?

If they mean "redirect stdout to FILE" and "redirect stderr to FILE", then all you could so something like :

( ( YOUR_COMMAND ) | bzip > $file_1.fastq.bz ) 2>1 | bzip > $file_2.fastq.bz

Where YOUR_COMMAND is the same as what you're doing, just without the -1 and -2.  The idea here is to send stdout down one pipeline and stderr down the other.  Yeah, it's a bit rickety. (If there's an error being reported earlier in your pipeline, it would show up in file 2.)

If that's not what -1 and -2 mean, then... I don't know any tricks for that.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that works. The command takes one file as an input and kind of sorts it into 2 different files according to the content, so you have to specify the -1 and -2. Thanks for trying though!